# A maximum of a function on $S^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

Let $g$ be a function such that $g$ is $C^1$ on $\Bbb{R^3}$. Put $B=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R^3}\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1\}$.
since $g$ is continuous on $B$,  we have $\max_{t\in B} g(t)=g(u)<\infty$.

Now if $u\in \{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R^3}\mid x^2+y^2+z^2<1\}$ then $\nabla g(u)=0$ (where  $\nabla g(u)=(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(u),\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(u),\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} (u))$. So there exists   $a=0\in\Bbb R^3$ such that $\nabla g(u)=0 =au$.
If $u\in\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ then by [http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~gelineau/devagreg/Extremas_lies.pdf](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Egelineau/devagreg/Extremas_lies.pdf) $\exists a\in\Bbb R$ such that  $\nabla g(u) =au$.

My question why $$a\geq 0$$.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

We assume at $u$ the maximal value is assumed. Now if we have $\nabla g(u)=au$ with $a<0$, then we can show $g((1-\epsilon)u)>g(u)$ as follows: locally $g(u+\delta)=g(u)+\delta\cdot\nabla g(u)+O(\delta^2)$, so $g((1-\epsilon)u)=g(u)-\epsilon u \cdot \nabla g(u)+O(\epsilon^2)=g(u)-a(|u|^2)\epsilon +O(\epsilon^2)>g(u)$ when $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small. So prove by contradiction, we have $a\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yang Yang